# Drizzle React Component ContractData for array returns empty

Tags: solidity, truffle, react, drizzle

```
<ContractData
  contract="TheContract"
  method="getData"
  methodArgs={[accounts[0], "0", { from: accounts[0] }]}
/>
```

and a contract view function

```
function getData() public view returns (string, string, uint) {
  return (
    "x",
    "y",
    0
  );
}
```

The React component renders the

that you would expect for the return of an array but none of the list items.

I can confirm that the function does return the items in Remix.